The Chofetz Chaim's Shocking View of Baalei Teshuva
The Chofetz Chaim in Sefer Nidchei Yisroel makes some shocking statements about those born to parents who did not keep the halachos of Nidda.
See beginning of chapter 41, where he assumes that these children will be evil and rebel against God.
At the end of the chapter see here (middle of the first column), he states that these children will certainly be "Reshaim Gemurim". This contradicts what is said in the name of the Steipler that by learning Torah and performing Mitzvos these children are just like everyone else.
Additionally, see here (second column in brackets), where he also seems to disagree with Rabbi Moshe Feinsteins' view which states that if the mother bathed in other bodies of water, we can assume it was a proper Tevilah.
Does anyone know if his opinion is discussed by other commentators?

What is your actual question?

Has this opinion been discussed and refuted by other Rabbis? This is a very hard-line approach that can be devastating to those it applies to.

He's addressing parents, not children. Is it taking a hardline approach to warn parents about drinking during pregnancy and the harm it can cause to the child?

I’ve heard that rabbi akiva holds that kids born from these types of relations are mamzerim but we don’t pasken like that. So maybe Chafetz Chaim is just taking that one step further?

If anything, the Steipler and Rav Feinstein disagreed with the Chafetz Chaim, not the other way around (he lived before both of them, at most they would have been young men during his late years).

The context here is that the Chafetz Chaim is exhorting people to observe the laws of nidda by warning them of risks associated with failure to observe these laws, and the purpose of his writing isn't directed as a polemic against children of nidda.
The Chafetz Chaim is basing himself on the statement of Rabbi Levi in N'darim 20b:

וברותי מכם המורדים והפושעים בי אמר רבי לוי אלו בני תשע מדות בני אסנ"ת משגע"ח בני אימה בני אנוסה בני שנואה בני נידוי בני תמורה בני מריבה בני שכרות בני גרושת הלב בני ערבוביא בני חצופה

Translation (Sefaria):

The verse states: “And I will purge out from among you the rebels, and those that transgress against Me” (Ezekiel 20:38). Rabbi Levi said: These are children of those who have nine traits, who are defective from their conception and from whom rebels and transgressors emerge. The mnemonic for these nine traits is children of the acronym aleph, samekh, nun, tav, mem, shin, gimmel, ayin, ḥet.


The children of nine traits are as follows... children of ostracism [niddui], i.e., one of the parents was ostracized by the court...

This translation of "בני נידוי" (as referring to children who were conceived when a parent was under niddui excommunication) follows the view of a number of rishonim (Rashi ad loc., s.v "בני נידוי"; Rambam, Mishneh Torah, Hil. Isurei Bi'ah 21:12)
The Tur (EH 25), however, states as his primary interpretation that this refers to children who were conceived when their mother was a nidda:

בני נידוי בני נדה אע"פ שאינו ממזר מן התורה וי"מ שהוא או היא בנידוי שאסורים בתשמיש המטה וה"ה נמי אם אחד מהם אבל

Translation:

Children of niddui: This refers to children of a nidda mother, even though they are not biblically mamzerim. And there are those who explain that it refers to when either he or she is in niddui excommunication when they are forbidden to engage in marital relations, and the same law applies when one of them is in mourning.

In Beiur Halacha (240, s.v. "בני נידוי") the Chafetz Chaim cites both opinions, and actually presents the interpretation of excommunication first:

בני נידוי:    היינו כשהוא או היא היו אז בנידויים וה"ה כשהוא או היא היו באבלם... ויש גורסין בני נדה דאף דאין הולד ממזר מזה פגום מיהא הוי ועליהם אמר הכתוב וברותי מכם וגו' [פמ"ג]

Other authorities, as mentioned, have grappled with how to approach this issue from the standpoint of couples who wish to get married, when one of them was born from parents who were not particular to observe the laws of nidda. R' Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe EH IV, 14), for instance, says we can infer from someone's good character that the mother likely immersed herself in a body of water that constitutes a valid mikva (like the ocean) before her child was conceived, even if the mother's intention wasn't to observe the laws of nidda.
The Chafetz Chaim, when referring to "all the waters in the world", merely meant that showering is insufficient and that immersion in a valid body of water would be required (see Shulchan 'Aruch YD 201:1). As such, he would not necessarily object to R' Moshe Feinstein's reasoning.

I have found another place in the Chofetz Chaim's writings where it is clear that he would disagree with R' Feinstien's reasoning.
He states in the Sefer [Bais Yisroel] (https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14240&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=) Chapter 3 paragraph 3, that God-fearing people and "straight people" will avoid marrying children born from a Nidah mother.
Additionally, he cites the Zohar as saying that this impurity, which is greater than all impurity, will cause them to be born as "reshaim" and will never leave them.

@Bpsb But R. Moshe's point is that it may be that the mother was not niddah after all.

@Meir They are both referring to the same situation which is whether to marry a person whose mother didn't go to the mikva. The Chofetz Chaim feels that good people will stay away while R Moshe has creative reasoning to not be concerned. If the Chofetz Chaim would've agreed to R Moshe's reasoning then there would be no reason for him to say tha good people will avoid marrying these people.

@Bpsb There is an obvious difference between lechatchila and bedieved. The Chofetz Chaim was writing to get people to strengthen their observance of taharas hamishpachah; obviously putting in kullos, such as that swimming in the ocean might be effective, would be counterproductive there. R. Moshe is talking after the fact.

@ Meir The CC is also bdieved as he is referring to the children getting married which is many years after the woman didn't use the Mikva.
